# Why reducer function return only proxy? redux/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

My reducer function in state parameter (payload) returns the only proxy:

```
Proxy {i: 0, A: {…}, P: false, I: false, D: {…}, …}
[[Handler]]: null
[[Target]]: null
[[IsRevoked]]: true
```

My slice where is state proxy:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    currentUser: {
      loggined: false,
      isAdmin: false,
      jwt: false,
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, payload) => {
      console.log(state); // here is problem, but payload works very well
    },
    clearUser: (state) => {},
  },
});
export const { setUser, clearUser } = userSlice.actions;

export const currentUser = (state) => state.user.currentUser;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

here is redux store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/user/userSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: Your reducers don't do anything with the state, they don't return a new state or (as recommended by redux toolkit) "mutate" the state immer draft.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux Toolkit - I can't update Slice state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765280/redux-toolkit-i-cant-update-slice-state)

Comment: Thanks, guys, can you please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765280/redux-toolkit-i-cant-update-slice-state#comment116277698_65765733

Answer (score 13):

#### Proxy Object

Redux Toolkit allows you to "mutate" the state by using the [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) package to create a proxied draft version of the state.  You can safely mutate the `state` variable in your reducer functions because it is a proxy object and not the true state.  Behind the scenes, your mutations of the proxy are used to return a fresh copy of the state that reflects your changes.

When you `console.log` the `state` variable you are seeing this proxy.  You need to use the [Immer `current` function](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/current) which is [included in Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current) in order to log the true value.

```
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

```
reducers: {
  setUser: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
      console.log(current(state));
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
  },
}
```

#### Action vs Payload

Note that the second argument of the reducer is the whole `action`, not just the `payload`. The action is an object with properties `type` and `payload`.  This action object is created automatically when calling `setUser` with a payload.

```
setUser({loggined: true, isAdmin: false, jwt: "some string"})
```

returns the action

```
{
  type: "user/setUser",
  payload: {
    loggined: true,
    isAdmin: false,
    jwt: "some string",
  }
}
```

You can write your reducer function as `setUser: (state, action) =>` and access `action.payload` or you can destructure it as `setUser: (state, {payload}) =>` to get a `payload` variable.