# Redux Toolkit - I can't update Slice state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I wanna update the state and tried few ways to do that, but I can't.
First, I got a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65764486/why-reducer-function-return-only-proxy-redux-toolkit) with fetching state, as a result, I got proxy, not a state.

That is fixed by the `current()` function by the redux toolkit.
Next, where I have a problem is mutation main slice state.

Here is a reducer for mutating.

```
reducers: {
    setUser: (state, payload) => {
      console.log("before", current(state)); //init state
      state.currentUser = {
        ...state.currentUser,
        loggined: true,
      };
      console.log("after", current(state)); // here I have new state but...
      
    },
    clearUser: (state) => {},
  },
```

As a result, as a second console log, I got to state what I want, when I want to change a page or just want to do something with new data in the state, by  `useSelector()` redux function, as a result, I got old, not changed state.

Why has this happened?

Example of Slice state:

```
initialState: {
    currentUser: {
      loggined: false,
      isAdmin: false,
      jwt: false,
    },
  },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

[Reducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#reducers) of createSlice use immer:

> This object will be passed to createReducer, so the reducers may safely "mutate" the state they are given.

So you can either return a new object that is the new state or "mutate" it and not return it, from [createReducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer)

> you need to ensure that you either mutate the state argument or return a new state, but not both.

So you can do:

```
setUser: (state, payload) => {
  //state here is an immer draft, do not use that to copy current state
  console.log("before", current(state)); //init state
  state.currentUser.loggined = true;
  //not returning anyting
},
```

Not sure how you'd return a new state based on the old one since `...state` makes a copy of the immer draft and not of the state. Can't even find examples of doing this unless it's an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Works, but here is the next problem: 
After dispatching setUser and updating the value redirecting to another page where I have logic to check state using: ``const user = useSelector(currentUser);``, in ``user`` variable I got init, or old state, not updated?

Comment: Object spreads work fine with proxies. `return {...immerDraftState, field: 123}` behaves just like it would with a plain object.

Comment: @MiloshN. Are you sure the actions dispatch correctly and set the state to what you want (did you check redux devtools)? What is the selector that doesn't work and where is it called?